# no data-ad-slot google adsense vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, ads, adsense

I want to put google adsense commercial on my website which i built with vuejs. The idea was to use "vue-google-adsense" to show the commercial.

After I had a look at the VueAdsense Template, I figured that my code, provided by google, does not have any "data-ad-slot" (see picture below). I installed already "vue-google-adsense" and put the data as mentioned in the docu in my app but without the " data-ad-slot="1234567890" " line. My configuration in my vue file (where I want to display the ad) looks like the following:

main.js

```
...
import Ads from 'vue-google-adsense'
Vue.use(require('vue-script2'))
Vue.use(Ads.Adsense)
...
```

showdata.vue (where I want to display the commercial)

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    ...
      <Adsense
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      </Adsense>
    ...
  </v-container>
</template>
```

The problem I'm facing is that google does not find the commercial on my website. When I click "I've pasted the code into my site" (see picture) and confirm that with "Done", google doesn't find my commercial.

Do I do something wrong or do I miss anything?

Does anybody know why I don't have this data-ad-slot?

Cheers[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

my mistake. You first need to put the script shown in the picture above in your normal html code (for vue it would be the index.html after npm run build).

Then google checks and afterwards you get all the information you need ;)